# Passar Valor Por parâmetro PHP JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um pequeno trecho de código,logo abaixo.

Após o usuário clicar em uma div cujo ID é (click) esse código será executado.Tenho um código PHP que será executado dentro do bloco de código javascript.Quero passar para o PHP variável do JavaScript (Valor) no parâmetro do método  $status->verificarTipoUsuario(),ficando  $status->verificarTipoUsuario(valor).
É possível?

```
           $('#click').click(function () {

            var valor='exemplo';


           var recebePHP= "<?php
            $status= new Usuario_Control_Grupo();
            $status->verificarTipoUsuario();

            if($status==true) {
                echo 'existe';
            }else{echo 'inexistente';}

            ?>";
             });
```

Comment: O que você precisa é efetuar uma requisição AJAX. A **única** forma de JavaScript e PHP se comunicarem é por algum protocolo de comunicação - a mais comum é o HTTP. Pesquise sobre isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você utiliza web está usando uma comunicação HTTP de cliente-servidor. Isso significa que você realiza uma requisição HTTP para o servidor. O servidor por sua vez pega sua requisição e retorna uma resposta, normalmente um arquivo HTML. Que é interpretado pelo seu navegador.

Uma vez que o servidor devolve a resposta é impossível o PHP mudar algum valor sem outra requisição. Por isso seu código nunca vai funcionar assim.

Você tem que criar um arquivo PHP separado que APENAS escreve esse resultado que você quer. Dentro da página que você que fazer a checagem deve fazer uma requisição com Javascript para esse arquivo.

Pesquise por:

- Utilizar Fetch Javascript
- Ajax simples com PHP
- Comunicação Cliente Servidor.